# how to fix appending in the wrong row using open()

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a `CSV` file has two columns and has the header on the first row. it looks like:

```
95%  |  99%
     |
```

I try to use:

```
with open('XXXXX','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([a, b])
```

after I run this code twice, I tend to get result like:

```
95%  |  99%
 a   |   b
 a   |   b
```

but my output is

```
95%  |  99%a | b
 a   |    b  |
```

How can I make it right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output file doesn't end with a newline, so `writer` is just appending to the end of the last, unterminated line. If you know this to be the case in general and want to just append a newline before writing, you can do this:

```
import csv

with open('blah.csv','a') as f:
  # using \r\n since that's the default line terminator
  f.write('\r\n');
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['a', 'b'])
```

Another option is to read end of the file to check whether you need to append a newline or not, and only do so if the file doesn't have a line terminator at the end:

```
import csv

unterminated = False

try:
  with open('blah.csv','rb') as f:
    f.seek(-2, 2)
    if f.read(2) != '\r\n':
      unterminated = True
except IOError:
  pass

with open('blah.csv','ab') as f:
  if unterminated:
    f.write('\r\n');
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['a', 'b'])
```